# Django how to validate inlineformset so that a field of each form would add up to 100 percent

Tags: django, django-forms

I am building a form with subcategory using inlineformset. I use inlineform because I want the subcategory to nest under the category. I want to validate a field (weight) of each subcategory form to add up to 100%. I use the clean() but can't get it to work and the error message doesn't show up on the template. I have done some digging form the past posts but don't see any solutions. I also looked into djangoproject but got nowhere. Please help! What am I missing here?!!
In my forms.py I have:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Category, SubCategory
from django.forms import BaseInlineFormSet

class SubInline(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        allocation = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            if not hasattr(form, 'cleaned_data'):
                continue
            weight = form.cleaned_data
            allocation += int(weight.get('weight'))
            if allocation != 100:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Weights must sum to 100")



SubCategoryFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Category,
                                       SubCategory,
                                       fields = ['title',
                                                 'description',
                                                 'weight'],
                                        formset = SubInline,
                                       extra = 0,
                                       can_delete =True)
```

In my views I have:

```
class CategorySubCategoryUpdateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    template_name = 'manage/subcategory/formset.html'
    category = None

    def get_formset(self, data = None):
        return SubCategoryFormSet(instance = self.category, data=data)


    def dispatch(self, request, pk):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category,
                                       id=pk,
                                       owner=request.user)
        return super(CategorySubCategoryUpdateView,
                     self).dispatch(request)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = self.get_formset()
        return self.render_to_response({'category': self.category,
                                        'formset':formset})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = self.get_formset(data=request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('categoryportfolios:manage_category_list')
        else:
            print("100 is needed")
        return self.render_to_response({'category':self.category,
                                        'formset': formset})
```

in my template:

```
              <form class="form-horizontal" action = "" method = "post">
                    {{formset.management_form}}
                    {% for form in formset %}

                      {% for fields in form %}

                    <div class = "form-group">
                        {{ fields.errors}}
                        {{ fields.label_tag }}</br>{{ fields }}

                        {% csrf_token%}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                   <input type = "submit" class="button" value="save subcategories">
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your form class is `SubModelFormSet`, but in the view you are calling `SubCategoryFormSet`... please fix the code you have posted.

Comment: I have fixed the codes.